# error in running HelloGoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried the mapView tutorial of but it didn't work, I followed the first part of the tutorial

what is wrong with the code?

```
package tovar.hellogooglemaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;    
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

when it is run at the emulator the application crashes

Comment: please post the error from logcat

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Comment: `11-22 17:49:38.143: E/AndroidRuntime(243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tovar.hellogooglemaps/tovar.hellogooglemaps.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tovar.hellogooglemaps.Main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02840`

Comment: Did you add your activity in the manifest?

Comment: i think you're trying instantiate the wrong class. You also need to declare HelloGoogleMaps activity in your manifest

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
<activity
android:name="tovar.hellogooglemaps.Main"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>`

Comment: Hades you were right, thanks for the help